# minimize button is gray and non responsive, how do regain that function

Tags: macos, window, user-interface

I have a MacBook Pro and am running OS X Yosemite. The minimize button goes gray if the window is opened fully. This happened before and I found an answer online but am unable to find a solution now.
I am not at all familiar with code or much in the computer world. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What application is exhibiting this behavior? Is it just one program, multiple, or all of them?  When did this start and what changes did you make to your computer around the time this began happening?

Comment: "opened fully" ? You mean fullscreen? You cannot minimise a fullscreen window.

Answer (score 0):

Fullscreen windows cannot be minimised, as they take their own Space & there is nothing 'behind' them.

If you want to be able to minimise, then use Maximise rather than Fullscreen - Opt-click the green Fullscreen button; note the double arrow <> changes to the old (pre-Yosemite) + sign for maximise.